# templateDoesNotExist at / in django (what settings to do)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django.
The error is coming
`templateDoesNotExist at /`

There is one app in my project,I've put the template folder in the app
Structure is like:
Project_name , manage.py,app_name,SQLite

The structure of the app (app_name):
other files...
Inside template folder .. (Templates(folder) -> app_name(folder) ->HTML file)

What setting I've to do in settings.py of prj to debug this error.

Did I've to include path of every template of each app. ?
Like inside setting.py in Templates

`DIRS: ['BASE_DIR', "path"]`

Comment: You need to provide more information. How are you referencing the template file in your views.py? What is the actual path of the template file (relative to your project home)? Also paste the complete TEMPLATES definition from your admin.py.

Comment: you need to add the template folder, not inside your app directory, it should be onside of the app directory

Comment: @K.D What if I've three apps and all three have a file with the same name (base.html)?

So,the good practice is to define templates of each app inside the app folder.
And after all,on top level all the templates will be merged into one main template folder by django.

Comment: @apoorvgupta you will need to add into the template folder another folder for each app
template/app1
template/app2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
======== check & verify this ========
step-1 : check your app is registered or not

step-2: if your [templates] folder is in the app then go with the below setting otherwise put the path of your template in DIRS:['your template directory']

=== this is the default setting for a template if your templates folder in your application folder ===

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

step-3: check in views.py template name is correct or not
```

Comment: step - 1) My app is registered with the project in installed apps.
step - 2) The structure of the templates folder be like this:
App_name -> templates(folder) ->App_name  (folder) -> HTML files

So,Should I've to include path for every app's template folder ?